# Flask frontend with Tensorflow but not Tensorflow serving

Tags: json, numpy, flask, machine-learning, tensorflow

I have a simple Tensorflow 3-layer MLP model that takes a vector of 10 numerical values to predict a single numerical output.

My web app is under the Flask framework where a client can infer each minute a vector of 10 inputs to receive his prediction from my server where the Tensorflow trained model is.

My question: Is it necessary to go Tensorflow serving with gRPC for my simple application or is it better to find a way to pass an input if 10 values through a Numpy array from the Flask REST to my Tensorflow server? What's the impact of the latter method in the graph reinitialization? Does it need reinitialization in case of not adopting the "serving" property in Tensorflow? I really appreciate any help on finding a clean way to achieve a Flask/Tensorflow method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not necessary to use gRPC with TensorFlow Serving, that's just what we use in our examples and in the standard model_server. I'm not familiar with Flask, but you can have your own main.cc that creates a ServerCore just like https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/model_servers/main.cc but with a non-gRPC frontend.

This will have no impact on actual server model management like graph initialization and what models get loaded, it only changes the API to the server.

Answer (score 1):

I found it easier to just build a grcp client in python that I can import and use with Flask. The code is here, if you want to have a look:

https://github.com/epigramai/tfserving_predict_client/